# Expand content without wrapping up to a limit in an overflowed element on the cross-axis of a flex container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make some content expand as far horizontally as it needs to (based on the content size), without wrapping, up to a maximum size (say, `40%` of the width of the container), at which point it needs to wrap. If the content is higher than the container, it should overflow with a vertical scrollbar.

So far I've been using flex for this. A flex answer is preferable, but isn't an absolute requirement.

What actually seems to happen is that when the content overflows, the scrollbar isn't included in the width calculation for the ideal content size for `flex-grow`, so it grows as far as would be expected given the actual content size, but the scrollbar *is* accounted for when calculating content wrap, so the content wraps the last word or two of lines to fit the container minus the scrollbar width. This happens regardless of the content width and whether it reaches the max width or not, but is much more noticable when it doesn't reach the max width.

Note that in the real code:

- The content is actually nested inside a few other divs (not shown) for other reasons, but the problem can seemingly be shown without those intermediate containers.
- The outermost container uses `height: 100vh`, but limiting it to `100px` still shows the problem with less content needed to make it overflow.

This is a minimal example I made up:

```html
<div style="height: 100px; display: flex; flex-direction: row; overflow: auto;">
  <div style="flex-grow: 1"></div>
  <div style="max-width: 40%; overflow: auto;">
    <p>This is some text. This is some text.</p>
    <p>This is some text.</p>
    <p>This is some text.</p>
    <p>This is some text.</p>
    <p>This is some text.</p>
    <p>This is some text.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**:

After reading Michael's comment, I did some more digging and this seems to be a browser issue:

- In FF, I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqFk0.png) (wraps the final "text." of the first line)
- In Chrome/Edge, I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXUI3.png) (works as expected)

(I'm not yet allowed to embed images in posts, so these are links.)

So I guess this question is now "why does this differ cross-browser?"

Comment: Running your code and I don't see the problem you're describing. Perhaps I'm not understanding your question. Consider adding more details and/or images illustrating the problem.